# Wordpress Updating Cron Killing Database

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` on one of my sites that gets pretty good traffic, and my plugins are not causing any large writes to the database, but when I look at my database IO it has about 150-200 IOPS (writing) and about 2 reading.  It really shouldn't be that high, so when I logged in to MYSQL and ran process list, I get a bunch of cron updates.  However, this shouldn't be happening.

Is there another way to stop the cron field updates?

Here are some queries I see quite often but don't know why it should be showing if it's disabled:

```
UPDATE `wp_options` 
   SET `option_value` ='...extra long serialized string...' 
 WHERE `option_name` = 'cron'
```

There are also some options that get updated quite often as well (if you have tips how to disable or lessen them):

```
_site_transient_timeout_itsec_upload_dir
```

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Something may be still firing it up via http://your-site.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron

Comment: I use wp-cron-control to disallow direct access to this url.

Comment: Did you try to create a scheduled post and see if it'll get published? Are you using external cron instead of native WP one?

Comment: I have something to take care of schedule posts (just a simple plugin) but I am running crontab on a single server (its running in a load balanced environment) to manually trigger cron.